# Grid not showing up in perspective view

Tags: cinema-4d

Going kind of nuts here.  Grid shows up in other views except Perspective.  The Grid option is checked off in Perspective View.  Basically, when I open the program, there are no grid lines in the viewport.  It's a blank grey space.

I am new to Cinema 4D so I can't move forward until I can see the grid in perspective. 
Thank you if anyone can assist.

Comment: Why you don't check the Grid option if it is checked off ?

Comment: It's checked on in Perspective View.  When I go to Viewport Perspective > Filter and Toggle the Grid, the Top/Right/Front View are responsive but the Perspective View is not responsive at all.  Any ideas why it's not showing up even though the Grid Box is checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found what the problem was in the Preferences Panel. For those without an OpenGL card, like me, you need to uncheck use OpenGL in Edit > Preferences. The grid will then show up in Perspective View.